# Insert Object inside array of array

Tags: laravel, loops, multidimensional-array

I need to display 3 objects inside of 1 page of carousel. Maximum of 3 object per page. How will I do that using loop? or anything from laravel/vue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use chunk on collection

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]); //collection of objects, 1,2... are objects

$chunks = $collection->chunk(3);
$chunks->toArray(); // [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Use two foreach loop 1st for page 2nd for 3 objects